# How to convert movies in mkv to mp4 in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, video-conversion, pyffmpeg

I tried converting a mkv movie in my Google drive to mp4 so I can stream play it with Google drive player, so I used a popular ffmpeg colab note book and I got a response saying the file is not supported. Is there a way around this a and can I also use colab to convert the video in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on google colab:

```
! ffmpeg -i "path_to_input.mkv" -codec copy "path_to_output.mp4"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).